# Overloading the probability function

Tags: probability

I was just reading a paper on a technique to calculate probabilities of different types of ouputs, given unkown inputs.
While reading it, I stumbled over this line:

[Line here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dM7l.png)

The context is not that important,  it''s more what the notation means.
It's actually all fairly obvious, except for the two parts where there is a comma inside the probability functions. This happens in:

```
P(x,o|E)
P(E|x,o)
```

I know | is conditional, but has anyone ever seen a function like this given "two arguments" in this manner?

Comment: The comma just says which argument of the function is conditioned. I would expect the other argument to be independent with the conditional variable.

Comment: hm, ok so P(a,b) would be something like "probabilty of a **and** b"? and P(a,b|c) "probabilty of a **and** b, with b under the condition c"?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: the comma is in a sense showing the intersection of events

Answer (score 0):

In probability theory, the conditional delimiter "|" always separates the variables from the given. As mentioned in the comments, commas have lower priority in the "order of operations" -- they represent intersections of events.

Therefore, if we have:

$$P(X,Y,Z|A,B,C)$$ this is equivalent to the statment:

"What is the probability of (X *and* Y *and* Z) **given** we know (A *and* B *and C*) have occurred.